# How to stop drag to view on side menu ionic 1

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

We have an Ionic (v1.7.16) app. 
The layout of the app is a left side menu, main content and a right side menu that appears under certain circumstances.

```
<ion-side-menus cache-view="false>
  <ion-side-menu-content>
    ...
  </ion-side-menu-content>
  <ion-side-menu side="left">
    ...
  </ion-side-menu>
  <ion-side-menu side="right" ng-show="vm.showSideMenu">
    ...
  </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>
```

I want to disable the ability to drag open the right side menu. (Drag from the right side of the screen to the left to reveal the right side menu)

The `ng-show` directive appears to be working as it should but you can still drag to reveal the side menu.

Looking through the [v1 docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/api/directive/ionSideMenu/) I tried a couple things like setting a function on the `<ion-side-menu>` that returned `vm.showSideMenu` but that didn't work. I don't think I want to disable dragging altogether. There appears to be some directives that can handle this in later versions of Ionic but we are not upgrading this app currently.

Answer (score 0):

Use $ionicSideMenuDelegate

https://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/api/service/$ionicSideMenuDelegate/

In this use canDragContent(false); to disable the drag 
if you specifically need to disable the right side menu only then

> use $getByHandle('my-handle')   It returns delegateInstance A delegate
>   instance that controls only the ionSideMenus directives with
>   delegate-handle matching the given handle.

Usage :

```
$ionicSideMenuDelegate.$getByHandle('my-handle').canDragContent(false);
```

html :

```
 <ion-side-menu side="right" delegate-handle="my-handle">
    ...
  </ion-side-menu>
```